# Date output issue

Tags: java

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DatePlus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();
        //Date now1 = new Date();
        Date now2 = new Date();
        DateFormat currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

        int count1=10;
        int count2=15;

        Date addedDate1 = addDays(now2, count1);
        Date addedDate2 = addDays(addedDate1, count2);
        System.out.println(currentDate.format(addedDate1));
        System.out.println(currentDate.format(addedDate2));
    }

    public static Date addDays(Date d, int days) {
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        return d;
    }
}
```

both the date `addedDate1` and `addedDate2` output statements are printing the same date though the expected output is different.

Comment: It depends on what you want exactly, but adding a day to a date is not as simple as adding 24 hours. Some days have 23 or 25 hours, in case of daylight savings changes, and there might be other special cases.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you don't return a new `Date` instance but change the provided one. You always modify and print the same instance.

Change your function to

```
public static Date addDays(Date d, int days) {
    return new Date(d.getTime() + days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Comment: I *think* it's better, if more cumbersome, to go through an instance of `Calendar` and use its `add` method: I believe it handles oddities like leap-years, DST change... in a way that `Date` doesn't.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo That's true. I won't precise it in my answer because what we have here is fine for this simple addition but that's a valuable comment.

Comment: I would recomment the `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` class for calcualtions between NANOSECONDS/...MINUTES/.../DAYS instead of taking numbers and (maybe) forgetting one.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing your own method you can use [Calender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Date now = new Date();
//        Date now2 = new Date();
        DateFormat currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

        int count1=10;
        int count2=15;

        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(now); 
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, count1); 
        Date addedDate1 = c.getTime();

        c.setTime(addedDate1);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, count2); 
        Date addedDate2 = c.getTime();

        System.out.println(currentDate.format(addedDate1));
        System.out.println(currentDate.format(addedDate2));
    }
```

Comment: +1 I always use Joda-Time or Apache Commons and I forgot that this is also (bad) implemented in the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already in several answers/comments, doing these calculations manually is risky and error-prone.
Here is a basic example of what you need, using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) library, a very stable and well-design alternative to JDK Date, Calendar. etc...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();

    int count1=10;
    int count2=15;

    DateTime addedDate1 = now.plusDays(count1);
    DateTime addedDate2 = addedDate1.plusDays(count2);

    System.out.println(fmt.print(addedDate1));
    System.out.println(fmt.print(addedDate2));
}
```

Also, keep in mind that beside better design and clear documentation, Joda Time also is mostly thread-safe, as it always return **immutable objects**.
Finally, it's developed to be **interoperable** with JDK dates and calendars.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by *dystroy*, you are not creating a new instance and this is the problem.

By the way, you could use an external library like [Apache Commons Language](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to do this kind of logic, this is already well tested and you avoid such kind of problems. Commons Language has already an [`addDays` method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#addDays%28java.util.Date,%20int%29).

Even better, you could use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which also has this kind of methods.